# How to use Convector to querie CouchDB Rich Queries with JSON Objects?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, convector

I'm here with a problem with rich queries and convector chaincodes,  everything works with mango queries, but when I pass content object it's is stringifyed and don't will be sent has an object, but is converted to a string `"content":"{\"data\":\"1971\"}"`, obvious it fails the query

original sample query

```
{
  "selector": {
    "type": "io.worldsibu.examples.person",
    "attributes": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "id": "born-year",
        "content": {
          "data": "1971"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

graphql query variables

```
{
    "getByAttributeInput": {
    "id": "born-year",
    "content": {
      "data": "1971"
    }
    },
    "skip": 0,
    "take": 10
}
```

`packages/person-cc/src/person.controller.ts`

chaincode controller method

```js
@Invokable()
  public async getByAttribute(
    @Param(yup.string())
    id: string,
    @Param(yup.mixed())
    value: any
  ) {
    return await Person.query(Person, {
      selector: {
        type: c.CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PERSON,
        attributes: {
          $elemMatch: {
            id: id,
            content: value
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

in docker logs we can view that value is content is sent has a string and not a object ex `"content":"{\"data\":\"1971\"}"`

```
{"selector":{"type":"io.worldsibu.examples.person","attributes":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"born-year","content":"{\"data\":\"1971\"}"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick is change `@Param(yup.mixed())` to `@Param(yup.object())` and now it works has expected, we can query attributes content value with arbitrary and complex objects

```js
@Invokable()
public async getByAttribute(
  @Param(yup.string())
  id: string,
  // @Param(yup.mixed())
  @Param(yup.object())    
  value: any
) {
...
```